# Trying to connect"neither an image nor a build context specified."

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Running docker-compose commands like build and up works.

However when I try to connect docker with VS Code I get this error:

```
The Compose file is invalid because:
Service your-service-name-here has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
```

This is the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build: .
    command: bin/rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
```

Comment: That error message doesn't appear to match the compose file shown. Does the error literally show "your-service-name-here"?

Comment: Yes it does literally show "your-service-name-here".

Comment: Maybe the problem is that it doesn't recognize this file? But when I open the folder it immidiately asks something like "connect with docker" so it has to recognize the file, right?

Comment: The file you are showing and the file VS Code is using are not the same.

Comment: The file is called docker-compose.yml How could I find out which file VS Code is using?

Answer (score 3):

I very probably that your should be specific build context

```
build:
  context: . # if you stay on root project
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your devcontainer.json in the .devcontainer folder. Mine had an autogenerated docker-compose.yml from a previous experiment and it was a partially-filled template which could not work, hence the error message.

Found this by looking carefully at the command VSCode was trying to execute (the -f argument).

Cleaning up the .json config file solved the issue.

Comment: Likewise, this can occur if you have a `docker-compose.override.yml` which is out of sync with your `docker-compose.yml` (eg: old service names with context/Dockerfile no longer available)